# Why do we need to make simulation not only on baseband but also on passband?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, signal-analysis

What is the purpose of doing passband simulation, what are the signal processing  imperfections we can reproduce in passband?
In other words what are we missing if xe simulate only in base band?

It is IQ imbalance, time/frequency estimate,  matching filtering ... ?

Comment: I think most if not all the times a passband simulation is done, it is because the user just simply isn't aware that the baseband analytic signal is equivalent (and so much easier to model!). So I will be interested to see if someone can offer a good reason.

Comment: What happens if you have a nonlinear channel (say, a power amplifier that might be described as a memoryless clipper). For a rapidly varying sinoidal passband signal (say, a constant information-carrying signal), new harmonics would be introduced, «splattering» energy away from the center frequency. If the same was modelled as a complex baseband, the same clipper would reduce the DC signal, but not introduce new harmonics?

Comment: @Knut You just model the non-linear channel at its equivalent baseband signal; all harmonics of concern would be within the baseband signal-- for the PA, do you really care about the third harmonic of the carrier which is immediately filtered out in the Tx filter? You care about the spectral regrowth into the adjacent channel which is modelled quite well using this approach (although what complicates it in either case is the memory effects from thermal heating which can result in accuracy differences when modelling spectral regrowth due to non-linearity alone).

Comment: So with your example - What is always of concern is the envelope not the carrier itself- so if you had a rapidly varying sinusoidal envelope in the passband (of phase or mangitude)-- this would be a sideband in the passband and a tone at baseband, and in the baseband signal under hard clipping you will still get all the odd harmonics just the same way. You would need to have a sampling rate high enough to capture all those harmonics without aliasing in your simulation but the results would be identical.

Comment: And it is the lower frequency offsets that will have harmonics in band or immediately adjacent which are of most concern since they cannot be easily filtered.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I guess my intuition was that nonlinearity usually is taking the nice analysis tools away from us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, we'll have to look at two things: Passband Signals and Passband Systems.

Let's start with the general notion that the consideration in domain A is equivalent to  consideration in domain B if there's an invertible mapping between A and B that covers all possible inputs and outputs of the consideration.

## Signals

That mapping for the complex baseband and real passband domain for signals is well known; mathematically, it's the Hilbert transform, followed by multiplication with a complex exponential of negative center frequency of the passband.

In the other direction, it's the multiplication with a complex exponentionential of a frequency high enough so the complete baseband is at positive frequencies, and then removal of the imaginary part.

That immediately posts three requirements:

1. The Hilbert transform must be well-defined
2. There must be a center frequency for the passband signal
3. There must be a frequency higher than half the bandwidth of the baseband signal.

2 and 3 are equivalent, as far as I can see – you can only use baseband if your signal has been a passband signal before¹.

About the 1. requirement:

Tough one, I've been trying to generally state a domain of definition for the Hilbert transform, but that's nothing for a lazy Sunday noon. Concretely, and function $f(t)$ that fulfills

$$\left\lvert\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t-\tau}\right\rvert < \infty$$

is Hilbert-transformable, and you need to account for the fact that you can use all your Lebesgue intergral magic here (you'll really have to, that thing usually has a singularity, and that is an example often used to motivate Cauchy's principal value theorem for electrical engineers).

Now, if $f\in L^p,\, p>1$, then that's a given; but periodic (and hence, not-energy-)signals do work too; tempered distributions do, and a few other things.

Considering the fact that Parseval's theorem already tells us that, inherently, a signal that's limited in energy in frequency domain (and every band-limited signal has to be) needs to be in $L^2$, we can infer that there is *none* band-limited passband signal that you cannot equivalently observe in baseband.

## Systems

This is the tricky part. We're looking for passband systems that we can't map back and forth from passband to baseband.

---

¹ – that's true for more than signals with closed interval support; compactness suffices, as far as I can tell, but your mixing function then is no longer a single complex exponential. For example, you could have an infinite real tone comb with frequencies $N\pi,\,N\in\mathbb N$, and your mapping to baseband could be Hilbert followed by multiplication with a complex tone comb $\sum_{m\in\mathbb N} e^{jmt}$, and would still end up with a proper baseband, and a way of converting that back to "strangely defined passband". But that's more about generalizing the notion of pass- and baseband than it goes to answer the question...

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing, Marcus! I've used baseband equivalents for years without knowing the deeper mathematical idea behind it, of the Hilbert transform. Thought that it was just a convenient "representation" for the passband signal. Is there a good reference where we could learn more about how it relates to the Hilbert transform?

Comment: that was the way it was introduced in my Signals & Systems lecture and the accompanying textbook, Jäkel & Kiencke: "Signale und Systeme" (modern edtions by Jäkel & Puente). Hm. neither [Tse](https://web.stanford.edu/~dntse/papers/book121004.pdf) (which I otherwise recommend very much!) nor [Lapidoth](https://www.afidc.ethz.ch/A_Foundation_in_Digital_Communication/Getting_the_Book.html) (which is usually pretty nice for the math explanations) do that strictly, Oppenheim's Discrete-time SP assumes it's already done; lemme check my older Proakis editions

Comment: ah yes,Proakis does it: "Representation of bandpass signals and systems", introduces it constructively. Section 4-1-1 in my third edition of Proakis' *Digital Communications*.

Comment: Thanks for checking! I wonder where my Proakis went, will have to look for it :-).